# Как записать эту формулу в C++

Tags: c++, математика

Никак не могу понять, как записать эту формулу, перепробовал кучу вариантов, но ни один не подходит.
Вот последнее, на чем я остановился: pow(cos((3/8*M_PI-a/4)),2)-pow(cos((11/8*M_PI+a/4)),2); Буду рад любой помощи[image: формула]

Comment: Этот  вопрос  не имеет отношения к С++

Comment: @ARHovsepyan В принципе имеет - как *правильно* записать на С++...

Comment: @Harry, но если знать алгебру, то и для записи  на С++  не возникнет вопрос

Comment: @ARHovsepyan У него проблема в целочисленном делении - при чем тут алгебра?... это чистое знание языка.

Answer (score 2):

Ваша проблема, что вы написали 3/8 и 11/8, а не 3./8. и 11./8. - потому что вы написали *целочисленное* деление, которое выполняется с отбрасыванием дробной части, так что первая дробь у вас равна 0, а вторая - 1...

```
pow(cos((3./8.*M_PI-a/4)),2)-pow(cos((11./8.*M_PI+a/4)),2);
```

Надеюсь, `a` у вас имеет тип `double`? Не `int`, случайно?

Но я бы рекомендовал записать эту формулу как

```
sin(a/2.)/sqrt(2)
```

Так оно и проще, и быстрее...

Comment: в первом случае на точках можно было бы и сэкономить, например `3./8`

Comment: @Zhihar Это принципиально? :) И вообще, `1.1780972451-a/4`...

Comment: Ох, этот стэковерфлоу... в одном ответе предлагают вместо `&` всегда писать `bitand` в другом точки экономят :D